# Facing problem of '/home' partition

Tags: dual-boot

I installed Ubuntu along with windows 10.when I install it,I chose "something else" and installed.Because i wanted to have separate '/home' partition.But i cant view that home partition as a separate partition.It appears as a folder inside the "files". But i can view my other two windows partitions as separate partitions in side panel ?

Output of `cat /etc/fstab`:

```
# 
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a 
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5). 
# 
# <file system> <mount point> <type> <options> <dump> <pass> 
# / was on /dev/sda5 during installation 
UUID=924e32ac-04aa-4b15-a7cd-420fa259f826 / ext4 errors=remount-ro 0 1 
# /home was on /dev/sda6 during installation 
UUID=8d775a19-adf1-4064-a0c4-9d2a7b3ed638 /home ext4 defaults 0 2
```

Comment: Will you add the content of your `/etc/fstab` to your question?

Comment: Please open a terminal window and run a command in it, `cat /etc/fstab`; Press 'edit' under your original question and copy and paste the output of the command into the editing window. Indent each line [of the pasted output] four spaces to render it as 'code'. And save your edited question.

Comment: "bash: /etc/fstab: Permission denied " this is what it says when i run "/etc/fstab"

Comment: I typed and run "cat /etc/fstab"   output says "# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>

Comment: # / was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=924e32ac-04aa-4b15-a7cd-420fa259f826 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /home was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=8d775a19-adf1-4064-a0c4-9d2a7b3ed638 /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
"

Comment: paste all means ? above comment ?

Comment: It is difficult for us to read the output, when you pasted it into comments, but it looks good, there is a line with `/home`, so I think your system is working like it should (and described in the answer by @user68186).

Comment: i pasted the output under my original question... sorry if i troubling you.. i really want help from you guys..i need to shift to ubuntu from windows..but can't do it with these problems

Comment: ok i will list out my all questions... wait brothers

Comment: can you tell me, is it possible to show you my desktop,is there any option to tag a screen shot of my desktop

Comment: This is a question answer site. Please don't ask all questions under one question. Ask separate question if needed. See the [Help](https://askubuntu.com/help) for how to ask questions here. You can upload your screenshots at imgur.com and put the link in your question.

Comment: sorry if i trouble..actually this is my first day ,im using this site.so dont have much idea on how to comment

Comment: i installed wine(development version),but cant find it by searching, i tried to copy files to home folder innside files.but can not do it

Comment: These are different questions. Search the site for similar questions and then ask new questions by pressing the **Ask Question** button on the top right side of the web page.

Answer (score 4):

## This is normal

Ubuntu, and Linux in general work differently from Windows. In Windows, partitions show up as `C:\`, `D:\` etc. In Ubuntu partitions are mounted into empty directories or folders.

## Automatically mounted partitions

Some partitions are mounted automatically when the system starts. This is governed by the file `/etc/fstab`. In your case, two partitions are mounted automatically, the `/` partition, also known as the system partition or the root of the file system. The other is is the `/home` partition. Once the `/home` partition is mounted, the `home` folder under the `/` partition becomes the `/home` partition. This partition has your `Home` sub-folder such as /home/username`. Anything you put in your Home folder goes directly into the partition.

In your case, the `/home` partition is mounted at the `/home` folder. When you installed Ubuntu, and assigned `/home` as the mount-point for the ne partition, the installation process set it up so that the partition is automatically mounted at that mount-point every time the system starts. That's why you don't see it as a mountable partition inside `Nautilus`, also known as `Files` app.

The partitions that are automatically mounted at system startup are governed by the file `/etc/fstab`. You can see the contents of `/etc/fstab` by opening a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and entering the command:

```
cat /etc/fstab
```

If you see a line with `/home` in it, then your `/home` partition is mounted at that folder when the system starts. It has to be done this way. Otherwise you will not be able to use the partition as your `/home` folder.

## Other partitions not mounted by default

You have two other Windows partitions. These partitions are not mounted automatically when the system starts. Your `/etc/fstab` file does not have any reference to these partitions. Therefore, they show up as drive icons on the left panel of the `Files` app. When you click on one of them they will be mounted on a temporary folder. Inside that folder, you will find all the sub-folders of that partition. To unmount such a partition, click on the *Eject* icon next to it on the left panel.

If you want to mount your Windows partition at system startup, you will have to create a mount-point folder (or select an existing empty folder) and edit the `/etc/fstab` file. For example, if I want a separate partitions for my music. I can create and format a partition. Let's call this partition `/dev/sda6`. In Windows, the partition is given a new letter name, such as `E:\`. This does not happen in Ubuntu. **In Ubuntu you have to mount a partition to a folder so that you can use it.** In my case, I want to mount this partition in the folder `/home/myusername/Music`. This `Music` folder already exists. If if didn't I would have to create this folder. Then I can mount (think it as assigning) this folder to this partition. This folder is then called **the mount-point** for this partition.

**You don't have to do anything. Everything is working normally.**

Hope this helps

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75802/discussion-on-answer-by-user68186-facing-problem-of-home-partition).

Comment: I am in the above chat room now if you still want to discuss.

Answer (score 0):

**If you don't want your windows files to show in Ubuntu:**

Then you would have to encrypt your windows partition using windows 10 system programs or third party apps. However, the encryption will be performed using your Microsoft account credentials as key. Assuming you didn't have the option to select "encrypt whole disk" when installing Ubuntu (or maybe you just encrypted just your /home folder), your Ubuntu files will also be visible in windows.

**Generally speaking**
We can't expect the operating systems to have been designed to work alongside each other. Keeping this in mind, I don't recommend dual booting unless you absolutely have to.

Comment: actually i too don't like to have dual booting. but at this scenario i cant ignore windows totally.because still i have not clarified my problems and i'm following a BSc. so ppt's and to do assignments  i want windows

Comment: I totally hear you, unfortunately the universities usually promote using proprietary softwares, because they take commissions. If you'd like, you can use your windows laptop to satisfy your school projects and use linux (preferably on a different machine) for your own. I did my PhD project in physics solely using Unix and nothing bad happened.  Good luck with everything!

Comment: no no..that is not because of my university. i cant do the assignments in ubuntu ,because still i cant use ms word and ms pwerpoint on ubuntu.that's why.

Comment: if i can do everything on ubuntu, that i have been doing in windows up to now, then definetely i will shift to ubuntu

Comment: I see. So that is great, you are on your way to freedom ... :-)